# jQuery Tools (horizontal accordion) combined with jQuery UI (tabs)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface

Hello everybody and thanks for taking your time.

I got an existing project where the main-page uses a horizontal accordion for the main content area from jQuery Tools (the Tabs element).

Now i have to implement a Tabs-menu (into one of the existing accordion pages) which is build with jQuery UI (the main container are Tabs and inside of them are several nested accordions).

Is there any easy way I can solve this problem and combine jQuery Tools with jQuery UI?

I did a search-replace on the tabs code of jQuery UI (js+css) and changed everything from "tabs" to "tabsnew".. 
The script seems to work with this, but the css is not working correctly with this (even tough I changed all elements which are used to build up the Tabs).. I think there must be an easier solution for this..

I'm very thankful for any ideas or solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Drop jQuery UI and implement the tabs again in jQuery Tools. If this is production code for a website there's no reason the users should load both libraries.